# Backbone.js display JSON in template using underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm pretty new to BackboneJs and I'm trully lost there, an all day lost facing this maybe simple problem.

I try to create an app which **runs offline.** So i don't use any model or collection, and strange things like .save, .fetch.
I only use Backbone for history, structure and templating system.

My question is. I have some JSON, how can I display it in my template ?

- My View, all is working til there. My json is in the jsonVar.

  ```
  window.ExposView = Backbone.View.extend({
      template:_.template($('#expos').html()),
      render:function (eventName) {
          console.log(jsonVar); // it's ok here
          $(this.el).html(this.template(),{"output":jsonVar});
          return this;
      }
  });
  ```
- My Template (using jQuery mobile at the same time), I want my Json to show there.

  ```
  <script type="text/tempate" id="expos">
      <div data-role="header" class="header">
          <a href="#" data-icon="back" class="back ui-btn-left">Back</a>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content" class="content">
          <%= output %>
      </div>
  </script>
  ```

**Error : output is not defined**.. Well

Another question.
If by any miracle my template receive my json output, how can I display it using underscoreJs ?

Thanks for your time, 
have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just got the syntax slightly off -- a compiled template is a function that you pass the JSON model to.  Like this:

```
$(this.el).html(this.template({"output":jsonVar}));
```

There are a number of ways you can render, but I guess you want to just add the markup to the DOM.  Try something like this:

```
var view = new ExposView();
$("body").append(view.render().el);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hDQ6T/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. You just need to call the template function with the object.

```
$(this.el).html(this.template({"output":jsonVar}));
```

Comment: I knew it was simple, but not THAT simple. Thx a lot !